# How to OrderBy and SelectTop5 with EF before selecting all rows into memory

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to select top 5 rows and ordered-descending by Id column without getting all rows into memory.

My code:

```
IList<Article> articles = _articleRepository.GetList(d => d.CategoryId == cat.Id)
                                            .OrderByDescending(d=>d.Id).ToList();
```

I know this first gets all rows into memory and apply OrderBy and Top5 rules in memory and I believe there should be another way to this? I would like to apply these 2 rules before getting them all into memory How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need access to an `IQueryable` and perform the following LINQ:

```
dbContext.OrderByDescending(d => d.Id).Take(5).ToList();
```

This will convert the LINQ expressions into SQL and only fetch the relevant rows from the database. The `ToList()` will execute the query and load the five elements into memory.